# Websocket with Locust, no error but no data

Tags: websocket, locust

The fixed code (from https://medium.com/@rajatsaxena120/websockets-in-python-d91c7bc2fd22, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?newreg=520c9b343e534667aa88f67ea3f79cb4) seems to work:

```
import time, websocket
from locust import HttpUser, task, between, events
from websocket import create_connection
import gevent

class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)
    @task
    def on_start(self):
       ws = create_connection('wss://REDACTED.com')
       g = gevent.spawn(self.connect)
       g.get(block=True, timeout=10)
       g = gevent.spawn(self.subscribe)
       g.get(block=True, timeout=10)
       g = gevent.spawn(self.send)
       g.get(block=True, timeout=10)       
       
    def _receive():
       ws = create_connection('wss://REDACTED.com')
       while True:
          res = ws.recv()
          events.request_success.fire(
             request_type='Websocket Receive Message',
             name='test websocket message receive',
             response_time=0,
             response_length=len(res)
          )
    gevent.spawn(_receive)
```

But when running tests, nothing happen, no connection to websocket, no load on the server.
What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual problem is, but you should not decorate your on_start method with @task. Either run something for each iteration (@task) or once, when the user is started (on_start)

Comment: In general, I recommend running your code in a debugger (or just use print-debugging), to see what is actually going on. locust-plugins provides an easy way to run in the debugger: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/debug_ex.py